# Image processing degradation function with matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transform, blur

I am very new to matlab and image processing toolbox.

I have a source image in matlab. I need to blur this image by taking the Fourier transform of it and then multiply it with H(u,v). At least I need take the inverse transform. H(u,v) is given below. How can I do it with matlab. PI is the PI constant in math. 
[image: Degradation function]

Comment: This blog post uses Python and Numpy but the function names are similar to Matlab. http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2011/08/fourier-transforms-and-image-filtering.html   I found the post very useful when I was recently learning FFT/IFFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look `imfilter` function from Image Processing Toolbox. If this function is not appropriate for you then you can use `fft2` and `ifft2` functions to do forward and backward Fourier transform.